# Laravel Mix Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-mix

I've searched and searched and I can't find the answer to my problem on SO. So here's my issue. I'm trying to load jQuery Globally using Laravel Mix. I've tried modifying all sorts of files, and nothing seems to be working... I'm still getting the "$ is not defined" error.

Here's my code.

Bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/select2.min.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin/app.scss', 'public/css/admin')
   .copy('resources/assets/css/fontawesome.css', 'public/css')
   .copy('resources/assets/css/select2.min.css', 'public/css')
   .copy('resources/assets/webfonts', 'public/webfonts')
   .copy('resources/assets/js/tinymce', 'public/js/tinymce');

mix.browserSync('http://localhost:8000');
```

Error I'm getting:

[image: Error Screenshot]

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Code on inside of create.blade.php in the @section('scripts')

```
<script>
   $(function(){
        alert();
    });
</script>
{{-- Tiny MCE --}}
<script src="/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: 'link',
        menubar: false,
        branding: false,
        resize: false,
        statusbar: false,
        force_br_newlines : false,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '',
        toolbar:    ['undo redo | cut copy paste | removeformat',
                    'bold italic underline | link | outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify alignnone',],
    });
</script>

{{-- Image Javascript --}}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        // We can attach the `fileselect` event to all file inputs on the page
        $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
            var input = $(this),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
            input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
        });

        // We can watch for our custom `fileselect` event like this
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

            var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

            if( input.length ) {
                input.val(log);
            } else {
                if( log ) alert(log);
            }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

AND finally my layout file

```
<!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

        {{-- Page Specific Scripts --}}
        @yield('scripts')

    </body>
```

What am I doing wrong?!?!?

Console.log(e) returns nothing... which means jquery should be loading correctly but isn't.

[image: this is the app.js file]

[image: Still giving same error]

Comment: Catch the error ..?

Comment: from a brief look, try maybe wrapping your code with on load without depending on jQuery. Maybe it breaks on that point

Comment: @Teemu how would i do that?

Comment: ?? You've wrapped jQuery loading into `try..catch`, why not log the error message, if there happens to be a one.

Comment: That try catch was already there... i didn't write that... it came with laravel already installed

Comment: Change the catch block to `catch (e) { console.log(e); }` and see what/if there is an error in the console.

Comment: Still gives the same error. Nothing logged out. See attached pics above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `jquery` in laravel mix, import this way in your `app.js`:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: That does no longer work in laravel 6. I have in `bootstrap.js` line:

```try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
``` and still have that problem

Comment: @Sebastian try change it to `global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on Laravel 6. You can do two things...

Or remove de `defer` from the script tag;

```
<script src=”{{ asset(‘js/app.js’) }}” defer></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src=”{{ asset(‘js/app.js’) }}"></script>
```

Or use jQuery after load event in your Blade template like this;

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   console.log($);
});
</script>
```

The `defer` attribute in a script tag is used when you want the script to be executed after the page has been parsed completely. So you can only make use of the loaded script once the page is loaded and the script is completely loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same errors with jquery in laravel. I have solved it by installing jquery via npm `npm install jquery` then I have imported jquery in the script that I need, like so:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

then `$` will be available in the js file.
After that I have called my js file in entry-point.js and run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me,

1. First ensure that you have installed 'jQuery'

`npm install --save jquery`

2. Next what @orangeman suggested - in app.js - as the first statement
   @courtesy [Orange-Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9587399/orange-man)

`global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');`

3. Then, running the following command

`npm install && npm run dev`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a different solution, so I am sharing in case anyone runs into the same issue as me.  I was using

```
 mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/dist/js")
    .vue()
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/dist/css")
    .extract();
```

on my `webpack.mix.js` file, but on the `layouts.app` file, I was incorrectly importing as so:

```
    <script src="{{ mix('dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

when the correct import script is this:

```
    <script src="{{ mix('dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('dist/js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('dist/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
```

This is necessary because when you use the `extract()` function, your js files and the vendor files are divided into different files, so by not including them, `$` was undefined.